# asymptotic for sums of binomials

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

from Stirling, we know the asymptotic for single binomial coefficients as $k,n$ go to infinity. Now I'm trying to estimate the order of a sum of binomial coefficients where $k$ ranges in an interval between two constant fractions of $n$. In particular, if $0\le a\le b\le 1$,
$$
\sum_{k=\lfloor an\rfloor}^{\lfloor bn\rfloor} {n\choose k} = ?
$$
and in particular, how does it compare with $2^n$?

Comment: This question can be addressed using results from large deviations, specifically Cramer's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem_(large_deviations) The answer mostly depends on how close the interval $[a, b]$ is to the mean $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you come up with an explicit formula addressing $a,b$?

Comment: If $b \le \frac{1}{2}$ WLOG the answer divided by $2^n$ will look something like $\exp \left( - n H(b) \right)$ where $H(b) = b \log b + (1-b) \log (1-b)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Are you assuming also $a=0$?

Comment: No, the answer doesn’t depend much (small multiplicative factor) on the length of the interval. The binomial coefficient varies through several orders of magnitude and so the sum ends up mostly dominated by its largest term.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Are you sure? I know that ${n\choose n/2} \sim 2^n/\sqrt n$..

Comment: That square root factor is the small multiplicative factor I mean.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan actually, I need exactly that factor. In particular, I need to know if the factor goes to zero, or converge to a constant

Comment: @Exodd if $a < \frac{1}{2}$ and $b > \frac{1}{2}$, the ratio of your sum to $2^n$ converges to $1$ by law of large numbers, for example. If $\frac{1}{2} \not \in [a,b]$, then the ratio of your sum to $2^n$ goes to $0$.